# Alexa developer console microphone issue

Tags: macos, speech-recognition, alexa-skills-kit

According to the prompt in the Alexa developer's console, one should be able to click and hold the mic image and then speak to Alexa.  This feature seems to be disabled for me (the microphone image is crossed out with a red cross, not sure what the significance of it is):

[image]

This occurs in various browsers, Firefox, Chrome, etc.  I'm on Mac:
[image]

What can be causing this not to work as designed?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
[image: alexa voice testing]
try clearing your browser's privacy settings and make sure it prompts you for permission to use the microphone. Grant permission to use the microphone and try again. To use the microphone it must not have an X and you click while speaking to the browser.